# How do I scrape Facebook Page Likes from my Fan Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know what Facebook Pages my fans Like.

I can manually find most of this information by logging into my Facebook Page's account and individually clicking people's names who have engaged with my page/posts and then reading their profiles, but I'm wondering is there an automated way to do this?

I am familiar with FB's Graph API and am pretty comfortable with programming an app to do this, I just need help with the formula / scripts on how to start.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to automated this, there is no API for it and scraping is not allowed on Facebook. You only get the Page likes of a user by authorizing that specific user with the `user_likes` permission.